When use webpack-dev-middleware and when node_modules is updated, how to apply new node_modules code and recompile all
I find webpack-dev-server cannot auto update node_modules new code, so I try following
const webpack = require("webpack");
const webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
const conf = require("../webpack.config.js")
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const fs = require("fs");

let server

const compiler = webpack(conf);
let middleware = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler);
app.use(middleware)
app.post("/todo", (req, res) => {
  compiler.inputFileSystem.purge()
  res.end()
})

const restart = () => {
  if (server) {
    server.close()
  }
  server = app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Example app listening on port 8080!")
  });
}

fs.watch("/home/roroco/Downloads/js/test-js/node_modules/test-lib/dist/TestLibC.js", (ev, filename) => {
  console.log(`filename:${filename}`)
  restart()
})

restart()

but it still use old node_modules code, so how to apply node_modules new code and recompile all

A solution could be to use the built-in watch system in Webpack, and ignore all the node_modules files except test-lib
module.exports = {
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules\/(?![test-lib])/
  }
}

